# C# LINQ/Object Initializers Example from C# 4.0 in a Nutshell

Tags: c#, linq, interface

I'm not sure I quite understand how the following example works. It's from **C# 4.0 in a Nutshell**.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" };

        IEnumerable<TempProjectionItem> temp =
            from n in names
            select new TempProjectionItem
            {
                Original = n,
                Vowelless = n.Replace("a", "").Replace("e", "").Replace("i", "")
                             .Replace("o", "").Replace("u", "")
            };

        IEnumerable<string> query = from   item in temp
                                    where  item.Vowelless.Length > 2
                                    select item.Original;

        foreach (string item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    class TempProjectionItem
    {
        public string Original;
        public string Vowelless;
    }
}
```

`IEnumerable` is an interface, isn't it? What kind of object is `temp` and `query`? Why does `TempProjectionItem` not need to implement `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TempProjectionItem` is the *element* type of the sequence... just like an `IEnumerable<int>` (such as a `List<int>`) is a sequence of `int` values without `int` itself implementing `IEnumerable`.

Note that there are two sequence interfaces: `System.Collections.IEnumerable` and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`. Obviously the latter is generic, representing a sequence of a particular type. So `temp` is a sequence of `TempProjectionItem` elements, and `query` is a sequence of `string` elements.

Neither of these is really a collection as such - the queries are executed lazily - it's only evaluated (starting with `names`) when you iterate over the data. Iterating over `query` involves iterating over `temp` which then iterates over `names`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable is an interface, isn't it?
```

Yes, it is. Actually in your code you are using `IEnumerable<T>` which is a generic interface.

```
What kind of object is temp and query?
```

In your code we can see temp is type of `IEnumerable<TempProjectionItem>`, while query is an `IEnumerable<string>`, both of which come from `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
Why does TempProjectionItem not need to implement IEnumerable?
```

TempProjectionItem is not IEnumerable, it's just an item of the `IEnumerable<TempProjectionItem>` which is a "container".